# Hide sheets based on Cell Value at Login

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a system using VBA for students to choose their classes in high school. Users are greeted by a Login Userform "LoginForm" for users to login. However, as their sensitive info is stored on sheets "studentinformation" which holds their information and "AMchoices" for their class choices, I don't want the students to be able to see this.

So, the code I have written reads their user ID and password from sheet "studentinformation" and opens up userform "AMForm" if correct. I only want the Admin login to have access to these sheets and therefore I want all sheets to be hidden from the students. I have set values in column G as "student" for students or "admin" for admin. The idea is that if the cell value in column G is "student" the two spreadsheets will stay hidden but if it is "admin" then the sheets are visible etc.

I have entered below my current login code. Thank you for your help :)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    Dim RowNo As Long
    Dim ID As String, PW As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If Len(Trim(txtUser)) = 0 Then
        txtUser.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Error. UserID cannot be empty."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Len(Trim(txtPass)) = 0 Then
        txtPass.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Error. Password cannot be empty."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set WS = Worksheets("StudentInformation")
    ID = LCase(Me.txtUser)

    Set aCell = WS.Columns(1).Find(What:=ID, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                   LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                   MatchCase:=False, _
                                   SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        RowNo = aCell.Row
        If Me.txtPass = aCell.Offset(, 1) Then
            MsgBox "Login Successful."
            Unload Me
        Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect UserID or Password. Please try again.", vbOKOnly
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect UserID or Password. Please try again.", vbOKOnly
    End If

    'Opening specific Userform
    If aCell.Offset(, 4) = "SBUB10" Then AMForm.Show
    If aCell.Offset(, 4) = "SBUB20" Then FMForm.Show
    If aCell.Offset(, 4) = "SBUB30" Then HRMForm.Show

CleanExit:
    Set WS = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Please find the time to give feedback and credit for past question you have here and got good answers, before coming up with new ones

Comment: Hi Shai Rado, I am sorry could not up-vote your help on my previous post because I have a score of under 15 from just joining. If there is another way to give positive feedback please direct me how as I am unfamiliar with this platform. However, I did leave a comment under your post saying that it was very helpful and the code worked perfectly. Thank you very much again for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An off-topic user experience hint first. Don't enable the login button until all pre-conditions are met. In other words, elsewhere in your code you have

`btnLogin.Enabled = Len(Trim(txtUser.Text)) > 0 And Len(Trim(txtPass.Text)) > 0`

**To solve your question**, you are looking to set `WS.Hidden=xlVeryHidden`. In conjunction with this, password protect the workbook **and** password protect the VBA IDE. Use different passwords for each.

You can now have a macro that asks for the workbook password for normal administration, but the sensitive data sheet can only be unhidden through VBA.

The other aspect of this is to re-protect the workbook on `Workbook_Open` (with the password of course) and set the flag `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`. Excel does not save this flag on closing so it has to be reset every time the workbook is opened. This flag means that all your macros can do their work without having to unlock sheets (except in some special circumstances).

Comment: Thank you AJD! This is great, not only does it work but it is highly informative :) have a good day.